# Calendar list always showing Person or Group field as Edited in the email alerts

Tags: 2010, email, people-picker

I've found this weird behaviour concerning *calendars*, *person/group fields that allow multiple users*, and *email alert notifications* that I haven't found luck searching a solution for.

## Steps to recreate

1. Create a `Calendar` type list on any site.
2. Add a new column to it. Set the type of column to be `Person or Group`. `Allow multiple selections` on this column.
3. `Set an alert` for that list. Have it alert you whenever anything changes.
4. Add an item to the list and fill in values for the `Person or Group` field.
5. Save and wait for the email notification to come through. `[Issue #1 here]`
6. Now edit the item. Edit nothing or anything other than the `Person or Group` field.
7. Save and wait again for the email notification.
8. Now edit the item *again*. Edit nothing or anything other than the `Person or Group` field.
9. Save and wait again for the email notification. `[Issue #2 here]`

**Issue #1**
On Step 5., we got an email that has all the values we put in with the exception of the `Person or Group` field. That one was blank.

**Issue #2**
On Step 7., we got an email that has all the values we put in including the value we put for the `Person or Group` field. This was marked as edited.
On Step 9., we got an email that has all the values we put in including the value we put for the `Person or Group` field. This was marked as edited even though there was not change in this field. Subsequent edits showed the same results.

What could be causing these issues and how do we resolve/workaround this? This only seems to arise on a `Calendar` list. I've tried this on a `Custom` list and I did not see these issues. I've also tried changing the email alert template from `Events` to something else, but this didn't do anything.